# Trying to call for an action. Vertical vs Horizontal

Tags: website-design, navigation, user-behavior, interface, ux-designer

I am trying to follow the concept I found here:

http://designmodo.com/cta-button/

I am not sure if I am biased or it is just really not calling my attention. I made 2 versions of it and here are the results:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

At first I would like not to use buttons at all and make the 2 div a link/button instead but I am having problem on how to make them look clickable. Maybe making it 3d by elevating them? Borders?

Answer (score 2):

As far as making the buttons stand out and look clickable compared to their surroundings, I think you've succeeded pretty well :-)

**I would personally choose your side-by-side setup**, especially if you're already dealing with the subject of categories and sub-categories. Your second setup risks implying the hierarchy between both. Having both options next to each other makes them equally important.

Suggestions:

- Try to align both buttons with each other. This makes for a more balanced layout.
- Remove the borders of the Category and Sub-Category divs. Less clutter is easier on the eye. Instead, try to use a vertical separator line between both.
- Make both buttons equally wide, but edit/shorten the text in your buttons. 'New Category' and 'New Sub-Category' are pretty much self-explanatory.
- If you absolutely need to differentiate both blocks more, try adding a unique image or icon for each block.

I hope this can help you move onward with your design.

Comment: Yep, I currently ended up with the side-by-side setup. I noticed I used a lot of space for the side-nav and narrowed it down. The other suggestions is useful as well. I'll try those